# How to view/edit x86 registry values in windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-registry

I have an application compiled with x86 processor that register a number of values in target machine registry. I have installed this application on windows 7 x64.
Now when I try to view the registered keys using regedit I noticed they're not there. Searching around I found out that there are two versions of registry on windows 7 x64. One for x86 apps, and another for x64 apps. Apparently in this situation regedit shows me the x64 registry.
How can I view/edit values for x86 registry?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the registry from a 64-bit application, you can see values for 32-bit applications under the `Wow6432Node` key (e.g., `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node` contains the 32-bit specific tree which is seen as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` from 32-bit applications). See the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more detailed information.

Comment: I was waiting for a 'yes'. There is Wow6432Node for Classes, too. So, no need for my first comment in the question..