# Create a Batch File That Adds a DWORD Value

Tags: windows

I'm trying to create a batch file that will add a dword value to a registry.

So far, it works manually when I do it "REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync /v EnableARIATelemetryFeature /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f"

Can someone help me translate it to a proper batch file?

I tried writing one:

@Echo Off
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync /v EnableARIATelemetryFeature /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

but nothing happens.

Can someone help me correct my syntax?

Thank you all for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Echo Off REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync /v EnableARIATelemetryFeature /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f` means that it should **Echo** the words ***Off REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync /v EnableARIATelemetryFeature /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f**

What you want is

```
@Echo Off 
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync /v EnableARIATelemetryFeature /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

In two seperate lines.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your reply.

I tried
@Echo Off 
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync /v EnableARIATelemetryFeature /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

2 separate lines but nothing happened.

Comment: Are you running the Batch file as Administrator? I think you should try  to add a `pause` as a 3rd line in the Batch file and run it (so you can see the resulting error)

Comment: Actually yes, I am testing it first on my own computer and I am an admin on my computer.

@Echo Off 
ECHO Add a DWORD VALUE
PAUSE
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync
/v EnableARIATelemetryFeature /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

My commands are indented, but for some reason, it's showing as a single line when I paste it here

Comment: Even if your user is an admin, with the normal setting (UAC) the Batch file will not be run with administrator rights unless you right-click on the file and press Run as Administrator. Have you tried adding `pause` in the batch file so that you can see the error?

Comment: Hello again, I tried run as admin, I placed a pause so I can see it running first but the dword value never gets added and there's no error message.

The batch file will just run and simply nothing happens.

Comment: The batch file runs and the command window remains open? Because if you add `pause` as the last line in the batch file the command window should remain open.

Comment: When I run the batch file, it will go in "press Any key to Continue' (because of the Pause Command) then it closes without adding the registry value.

Comment: Says nothing before the "Press Any key to Continue"? Possible a screenshot of both the open text file and the command window after it ran?

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your continued help.

See below the screenshots

https://imgur.com/sJKdRtf

https://imgur.com/MbL1YXk

Comment: Hi, the `pause` you want to put in a line AFTER the `reg add` to see the output after it runs. What you have now is that it waits until after pressing a key to run the actual Reg Add command and then closes without you seeing the success or error message.

Comment: Hello there, this is pretty embarrassing but I did what you told me (by placing the PAUSE after) and I found the error message.

Apparently, Desktop changed the PC I was using and my account wasn't Admin to the machine. I was double clicking the batch file.

I ran it and saw Access denied. I used it on my original machine and my batch file work.

Thank you for your patience and help. It was my bad. I'm sorry and Thank you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt mention your windows version. If you have a x64 Version, there is another possibility for an error.

With a x64 windows version there are two branches for the key, depending if you write/read with a x86 or x64 application

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ or HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\

[How to view/edit x86 registry values in windows 7 x64](https://superuser.com/q/600101/471143)

May be you check the key in the wrong branch ?

Comment: Hi,

I'm on Windows 64-bit.

I already have the .reg version and it works and it will also work if I manually open CMD and type in the command "REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync /v EnableARIATelemetryFeature /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f"

But I wanted a batch file where we can execute it rather than manually opening a command prompt.

Thank you.